# RxJS use response only from last promise

Tags: javascript, promise, rxjs

how can i only use the last promise created, canceling (or not using) all prior promises?

the function can be ran an unlimited amount of times.

```
rx.Observable.fromPromise(listingFactory.list())
            .flatMapLatest((e: any) => {
                return e;
            })
            .subscribe((e: any) => {
                console.log(e);
            });
```

Answer (score 1):

if your `listingFactory.list()` returns an observable of promises, then you could write :

```
listingFactory.list()
        .flatMapLatest((promise: any) => {
         return promise;
         })
        .subscribe((resolved_value: any) => {                     
          console.log(resolved_value);
        }, (error: any) => {
            console.log(error)});
```

`flatMapLatest` will wait for the latest emitted promise to resolve, discarding the previous promises. Note that those promises cannot be 'cancelled', but their resolved value (or rejection) will be ignored. Note also that `flatMapLatest` allows you to return an observable, promise, or iterable. In that particular case, we can then just return the promise directly without necessity to use `.fromPromise` operator. Also, the `fromPromise` operator expects only one promise as argument, not a list of them.

So what is the type of `listingFactory.list()`? How do you create your source of promises? Did I misunderstand your intent?